# I can't find the form that I built

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I created a windows form application. Everything was fine until just now. When I go into my project now I cannot find the Form1.cs [Design] tab which allows actual form designing with the rag and drop of object from the toolbox.

I checked the directory and I do have files and sub-directories, but being a C# beginner, I'm not too familiar with what files are needed.

So, could someone please show me how to get this back?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you deleted the file, you can bring designer up by pressing `F8`

Comment: Another option could be click on `Show All File` on your project and include the file if it is not included or hidden.

Comment: It is also important to remember to save all files (including the design file) when saving your project. Or, make sure you build the whole solution every time, otherwise, it won't save the design file. Something that constantly irritated me.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague. But if it isn't in your solution explorer, re add the files to the project.

Right Click on your project root -> New -> From Existing Item, navigate to said item and add it. (shortcut is Shift + Alt + A).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just code right click on it and select "View Designer", if you still have trouble try posting a screenshot.